Evaluating a yes/no field in Maximo automation scripting
In Maximo workorder I have a field called PAYBYPCARD which is a Y/N field in the Oracle database and represented by a checkbox on the workorder screen.
Whenever I activate this automation script which is an ON SAVE script
I get the following error
BMXAA3761E - The event has failed. Ensure that the event is registered correctly. See the log file in the APP HOME directory for more details about the error.java.lang.Boolean incompatible with java.lang.String

#PAIDBYPCARD SCRIPT
if PAYBYPCARD == 1  : 
   PCARDAMOUMT=True
   PCARDHOLDER=True
   PCARDPAIDDATE=True

I want the 3 fields listed after the if statement to be required if the checkbox is checked when you click SAVE.
The code
I'm just now getting back into MAXIMO scripting after many years of not doing it and I'm still trying to figure out the nuances of these things.
Thanks
I want the 3 fields listed after the if statement to be required if the checkbox is checked when you click SAVE.
